# illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i have a java application that use hibernate to connect with MySQL database. the problem is that when i try to delete any item, i get this exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a
>   proxy with two open Sessions

this is my delete code:

```
public void delete(Employee persistentInstance) {
    log.debug("deleting Employee instance");
    try {
        getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstance);
        log.debug("delete successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("delete failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: have you tried searching the exception? seems rather easy to fix

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you manage the Session properly. Once you are done with a Hibernate Session you should close it.

I suspect you load the Employee in one Session that you don't close, only to attempt to delete it in other Session.

Answer (score 0):

Modify code as below:

```
getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstanceDAO.getById(persistentInstance.Id();
```

Fetch the object from the database by its id which will refresh Employee object with current hibernate session before deletion.